# posts from ios app mis-identified as shares in activity log

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharing

when we post a link from our ios app, it appears correctly on the user's timeline with a 'via AppName.'

however, when looking at the user's activity log, our posts appear as follows:

'User has shared a link.'

on the other hand, when sharing via Zite, it appears like so:

'User posted something via Zite.'

Also, when clicking on All Apps in the activity log, the posts from our app are not showing up, while posts from Zite and Twitter are.

My question is, how can we make our app posts appear in the same way in the activity feed as those of Zite and Twitter and other such apps.

FYI our app is already in the App Center, and is live in the Apple store.

Thanks for your help!